# Python code returning error 'Object is not callable'

Tags: python, encryption

So, i have started playing around with encryption coding and have been trying to create a unique encryption key based from time. This is my code so far :

```
from threading import Timer
from pyclbr import Function
import hashlib, binascii, time

key1=""
buffer1=""
buffer2=""

class RepeatedTimer(object):
    def __init__(self, interval, function, *args, **kwargs):
        self.timer=None
        self.function=function
        self.interval=interval
        self.args=args
        self.kwargs=kwargs
        self.is_running=False
        self.start()

    def _run(self):
        self.is_running=False
        self.start()
        self.function(*self.args,**self.kwargs)

    def start(self):
        if not self.is_running:
            self.timer=Timer(self.interval,self._run)
            self.timer.start()
            self.is_running=True

    def stop(self):
        self.timer.cancel()
        self.is_running=False

def generateKeys():
    global key1
    global buffer1
    global buffer2

    t=int((time.time())/10)
    t=hashlib.sha1(str(t).encode('utf-8'))
    t=t.hexdigest()
    t=t.encode('utf-8')
    t=binascii.hexlify(t)
    t=t.decode('utf-8')
    t=t[0:11]
    t=int(t)>>5
    buffer2=buffer1
    buffer1=key1
    key1=str(t)

def printKeys():
    print("Keys : "+key1+" "+buffer1+" "+buffer2)

timerStart=RepeatedTimer(10,generateKeys())
#generateKeys();
timerStart2=RepeatedTimer(11,printKeys())
```

Whenever I run the above code I keep getting the error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-49:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 923, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 1189, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/Users/Kiro/Documents/LiClipse Workspace/EncryptionFinal/pkg/enc_keygen.py", line 22, in _run
    self.function(*self.args,**self.kwargs)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Exception in thread Thread-50:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 923, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 1189, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/Users/Kiro/Documents/LiClipse Workspace/EncryptionFinal/pkg/enc_keygen.py", line 22, in _run
    self.function(*self.args,**self.kwargs)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Does anyone have any idea why? What I want is the generateKeys() function to keep running every 10 seconds and the printKeys() function to tell me those keys every 11 seconds (to check that its assigning the keys correctly to the global variables).

This is more experimentation than anything but would like help in fixing this code as i would like to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

With your line

```
timerStart=RepeatedTimer(10,generateKeys())
```

you are handing over the result of the call `generateKeys()` to the `__init__` method. What you actually want to do, is to hand over the function itself. Then you must not call it:

```
timerStart = RepeatedTimer(10, generateKeys)
```